# Testing FastAPI endpoints in the interface

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I got access to a private GitLab project that contains the following branches: `main`, `develop` and `new_branch`. The machine learning project is pretty complex and contains various transformers for NLP, and many steps that generate some output from an input text. FastAPI has also been used. I am using Windows.

I followed the instructions and ran `pipenv run start`:

```
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Started server process [←[36m12988←[0m]
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Waiting for application startup.
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Application startup complete.
←[32mINFO←[0m:     Uvicorn running on ←[1mhttp://127.0.0.1:8000←[0m (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 and get (though the instructions say to go to http://localhost:8000/):

```
{"name":"my app API","version":"0.0.1","currentTime":"01/07/2022, 04:41:36"}
```

And in the terminal:

```
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:65248 - "←[1mGET / HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[32m200 OK←[0m
```

But how do I actually play around with the app? I saw a simple example on the internet where I navigate to the endpoint in the browser, but in my case the project is much more complicated and the tree of the folder is huge. Anything that I type after the address in browser, it gives me `{"detail":"Not Found"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since FastAPI is simply a framework for creating APIs, there is no real user interface available (aside from the documentation it generates). It's not a web app - just a collection of endpoint definitions.

From the FastAPI documentation:

[Interactive API docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/#interactive-api-docs)

[Alternative API docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/#alternative-api-docs)

If you want to know what endpoints are available in the application, try going to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/docs` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/redoc`.